# Adding new notification without deleting the old notification for my app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, alarmmanager

I am creating a TODO list app which accepts Notification time and date. Whenever i add a new scheduled notification my old notification get cancelled and the notification which i entered last alone works.
For example:
if i set a notification on 1,2,3 minute respectively i only get the final notification that is only one notification after 3 minutes.
Can someone explain how to clear this problem. If someone can pls share the code of broadcast and  the defining and calling part of notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, each notification replaces the previous one rather than generating its' own id. Fix that and you'll be on your way.

Comment: Do you have any source code regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your notifications have the same id.
When you call `NotificationManagerCompat.notify(id,notification)`,
use a different id for different notifications.

Comment: Do you have any source code regarding these kind of doubts